# Can't modify the PlaceHolderMain in my page layout Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, page-layout

I created a page layout for the "Design Administration" in Site Settings, and it generates two files (.aspx and .html).
I modify my .html with sections (div) but when I try to put a web part zone shows the following error:
[image]

Then I try to do the changes in aspx file but show the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not put server side tags directly onto .html design file. Yo should follow below steps to get the snippet for web part zone

- Go to design manager
  -Click "Edit Page Layouts" from the links in left side of page
- Click on your page layout.
- Click on "Snippets" on top right corner of page
- From the ribbon you should select the "Web part zone"
- You will get the snippet from the "HTML snippet" box.
- You can paste this into your html design template.
- Save the file. it will create a zone.

Below are reference links for page layout which tell you how to use page layouts and snippets

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/how-to-create-a-page-layout-in-sharepoint

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-snippets